# Incorporating location data in URL for weather API

Tags: javascript, web-applications, global-variables, weather-api

New to working with APIs. Can I use a variable like getURL in this way? It seems like this is close to working. Any help is appreciated - thank you!

```
    var location = "";
    var temp = "";
    var lat = "";
    var lon = "";
    var getURL = 'https://simple-weather.p.mashape.com/weatherdata?lat=' + lat     +'&lng=' + lon;
    var x = document.getElementById("weather");


    function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function getPosition(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude; 
    lon = position.coords.longitude; 
}

function getTemp() {
  $.ajax({
    headers: {
      "X-Mashape-Key": "FPsVzvZuHhmsh0ZOssY5pNKOxIDmp1hbTH5jsnSB5VtB0f307q"
    },
    url: getURL,
    success: function(response) {
      var respond = JSON.parse(response);
      title = respond.title;
      temp = respond.temp;
      $(".titleHere").text(title);
      $(".temp").text(temp);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: The lat and lon do not magically get updated in the string. You need to set the string when you update the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Lets break it down to a simple solution to see what is going on.

```js
var a = "1";
var b = "2";
var c = "foo " + a + b;
console.log("before", c);
a = "x";
b = "x"
console.log("after", c);
```

As you can see the string does not update after you update the variables, you need to build the string again. Another issue you have is you are referencing a variable `showPosition` and it looks like you defined it as `getPosition`.

Answer (score 0):

The comments mentioned are correct in that you're only setting the variables once, which won't work for your case. The other answer in this thread does a nice job in explaining why it's not being updated.

It looks like you have getURL, lat, and long encapsulated within a function. Since it is not available on the global scope, you won't be able to correctly assign the lon & lat values with the function getPosition().

We need to refactor your code so that it dynamically assigns values to an object that is accessible, create a helper function that composes the URL for us, and then invoke that function when constructing an AJAX request. The potential solution below was also slightly modified so that you can drop it in a REPL for testing:

```
// Generally want to avoid polluting to global scope, 
// so let's store our values into this object, config
var config = {}

function getPosition(position) {
    // getPosition will assign values
    config.lat = position.coords.latitude; 
    config.lon = position.coords.longitude; 
}

function buildUrl() {
    // using template literals to improve code readability
    const url = `https://simple-weather.p.mashape.com/weatherdata?lat=${config.lat}&lng=${config.lon}`
    return url;
}

function getTemp() {
    // notice that i replaced AJAX with this variable for testing purposes
    var test ={
    headers: {
        "X-Mashape-Key": "FPsVzvZuHhmsh0ZOssY5pNKOxIDmp1hbTH5jsnSB5VtB0f307q"
    },
    url: buildUrl(),
    success: function(response) {
        var respond = JSON.parse(response);
        title = respond.title;
        temp = respond.temp;
        $(".titleHere").text(title);
        $(".temp").text(temp);
    }
  };
  return test
}
```

// proof of concept

```
var test = {
    coords: {
        latitude: 10,
        longitude: 21
    }
}

getPosition(test); // simulate the passing of coords
console.log(config) // check to see if its assigned
buildUrl()
```